# How to handle array_shift() on Null?

Tags: php, fatal-error, php-8

Please take a look at this code:

```php
$end = isset($newvar) ? array($newvar) : null;
while($ends = array_shift($end)){
  ...
```

It was working well when I was using PHP `7.2`, but after upgrading to `8.1`, it throws:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_shift(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /path/to/qanda.php:469

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you should use `array_reverse` then `array_pop`, because `array_shift`'s complexity is O(n) and `array_pop` is O(1). Using `array_shift` might take very long on large datasets

Comment: You mean using both `array_reverse` and `array_pop` has a better performance than `array_shift's`?

Comment: You only need to use `array_reverse` once, and array_pop has a much better performance than array_shift: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php#112947

Comment: This really looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What's the point of the `while` loop here? Why not just `if (isset($newvar)) {  ...do something... }` instead of adding the value to an array just to use `while` to get it back as it were?

Comment: @Gugu72 - In this case, it's kind of a moot point since the array will never contain more than one single element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an empty array instead:

```php
$end = isset($newvar) ? array($newvar) : [];
```

[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) will return `null` on the first call with an empty array as input, so the loop will not execute.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic solution would be to replace the `null` value with an empty array to comply with the type requirements:

```php
$end = isset($newvar) ? array($newvar) : [];
while($ends = array_shift($end)){
```

You could also create the array and use the *null coalescing operator* on `$newvar`:

```php
$end = [$newvar ?? null];
while($ends = array_shift($end)){
```

But I don't understand why you would create an array with a single value and then create a loop using `array_shift`'s return value. The loop body will only run once.
Maybe just use a condition ?

```php
if (isset($newvar)) {
```

Comment: You raise a good point!